# Code works in IDE but doesn't work in Terminal Console

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, ubuntu, pycharm

My code works perfectly in Pycharm but I get an error if I type add in the Console (Ubuntu Terminal).

The error I get in Console outside of Pycharm IDE:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 37, in <module>
    getStr = input('>: ')
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'add' is not defined
```

My Code:

```
#!/user/bin/python3
class Item:

    itemsCount = 0

    def __init__(self, sku, bWidth, bHeight, bLength, quantity, bWeight):

        self.sku = sku
        self.bWidth = bWidth
        self.bHeight = bHeight
        self.bLength = bLength
        self.quantity = quantity
        self.bWeight = bWeight
        Item.itemsCount += 1

    def DisplayItem(self):
        print('[SKU : ', self.sku, '] [Width : ', self.bWidth, '] [Height : ', self.bHeight,
              '] [bLength : ', self.bLength, '] [Quantity : ', self.quantity, '] [bWeight : ',
              self.bWeight, ']')


items = [Item]


print('Dan\'s Warehouse Inventory')
print('Current Stock in inventory : [', Item.itemsCount,']\n' )


while True:

    getStr = input('>: ')

    if getStr == 'add':
        getSku = input('SKU : ')
        getWidth = int(input('Width : '))
        getHeight = int(input('Height : '))
        getLength = int(input('bLength : '))
        getQuantity = int(input('Quantity : '))
        getWeight = int(input('Weight : '))

        items.append(Item(getSku, getWidth, getHeight, getLength, getQuantity, getWeight))
        print(Item.itemsCount)

    else:
        print('Invalid command.')
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong... Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You are using different Python versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're *probably* running it under Python2 outside the IDE, where `input` is used to get a string *and* evaluate it as if it were a Python expression. It seems likely that you're entering the word `add` (since that's one of the things you compare the input against) and Python2 is rightfully complaining that it cannot evaluate it.

The Python 2 `raw_input` is equivalent to the Python 3 `input` so you could either use that, or ensure that it's run by *Python3* rather than Python2.

Comment: You are right! My Terminal is using python 2.7... I didn't noticed it before! Thanks!

Comment: I'm using 'pyton3 main.py' instead of 'python main.py' to run the code and it works now!